# Managing transitive package dependencies declared via uses constraints

Tags: osgi, apache-felix

I have bundles A, B and C. A contains a package 'a' that is depended on by code in packages b and c from bundles B and C respectively.

```
bundle A {
  package a

  export-package:a
}

bundle B {
  package b.a
  package b.b
  package b.c
  package b.d
  package b.e

  import-package: a
  export-package:b.a;uses:=a,
    b.b;uses:=b.a,
    b.c;uses:=b.b,
    b.d;uses:=b.c,
    b.e;uses:=b.d
}

bundle C {
  package c

  import-package: b.e,
    a
}
```

When I update all of these bundles together, I often get uses constraint violations (Felix reporting style):

```
Chain 1:
  C [47.1]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=a)(version>=1.1.0))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=a
  A [9.1]

Chain 2:
  C [47.1]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=b.e)(version>=1.0.0))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=b.e; uses:=a
  B [33.0]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=a)(version>=1.0.0))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=a
  C [9.0]
```

I was initially surprised that b.e generates a uses clause for 'a'. This is not declared in the Manifest nor the OBR repository.xml through which these bundles are provisioned. However, types in b.e expose types in a through their API, so I guess this is where it comes from.

The only way I find to resolve these is to increase the version number of the export and import of intermediate packages, e.g. b.e in this example. However, there are a lot of packages that ultimately use 'a', transitively.

**This means every time I update 'a' I also need to update all transitive dependencies on a with new versions.** Is it the correct thing to be doing to increase the version number of these packages? Is refactoring my code to be less interdependent the only other way?

Answer (score 3):

The uses constraints are not handled transitively by the resolver.

If bundle C imports b.e and b.e used b.d, then bundle C also needs to import b.d. That is, the public signature of b.e includes a reference to something in b.d. This is why we say b.e uses b.d. Therefore, any bundle which imports b.e must also import b.d. Otherwise the bundle cannot properly use b.e since some type referenced in b.e is not visible to the bundle.

For the export of b.e, it should state it uses b.d, b.c, b.b, b.a and a since using b.d means you also use b.c and so on...

Did you hand generate your uses clauses? Or was this example derived from something bnd generated?

Comment: Thanks for answering. No, the uses clauses were generated using PDE in the manifest editor. For b.e, a is not included in the uses clause, but b.d is. I figured that it's Felix that works out the transitive dependency through to a [edit: actually it may do transitively through the types in the API - will check this]. What I thought was additionally weird was that nothing in b.e exposes anything from a in its API. The other thing I need to check is the OBR repository.xml which maybe is defining these as requirements/capabilities...

Comment: I took a further look at the repository.xml. This does not have any further requirements from b.e to a. However, b.e's API does expose types from a in their Java API, so I guess this is why the uses clause is 'inferred' by Felix (having NOT been declared formally)? It feels like the only way around managing multiple package versions here and having these 'cascading' version updates is to combine packages more... although that feels a bit wrong. Note that the uses constraint violation only occurs at runtime. At restart, everything seems to work fine with the newly updated bundles.

Comment: I am not sure I would trust PDE's uses constraint generation. (I admit to being a bndtools/bnd fanboy!) Frameworks don't generate uses information; they just use what is provided in the manifest. If partial information is provided, you can get into trouble. Finally, a type from a "used" package does not need to be directly visible in a package for it to be used. Consider b.e.E extends b.d.D extends b.c.C extends b.b.B extends b.a.A implements a.I. b.e will only show a direct reference to b.d.D but the inheritance hierarchy is all "used".